# BIRT SPUDSOFT emitter excel report formula - not working

Tags: excel, report, birt

I am working with BIRT Reporing,now i have to use excel formulas in my birt report(like =A1+B1), so that when it export to excel it shows values in cell and formula in formula bar. after a long search on internet for this problem, there is an emitter called **spudsoft excel emitter** which can be used to export birt report to excel and it exports formula.[check here](https://bitbucket.org/yaytay/spudsoft-birt-excel-emitters/wiki/Home).

I have followed each and every steps as it is in the site, but the exported report does not shows values, instead it shows formula. I delete the formula and then typed the same, then it shows value and formula. Does anyone used this emitter successfully as they said(exporting formula)?

If so can you help me or any other way to do this?

BIRT version I am using is : BIRT 4.4.1

Comment: I suspect that when you exporting, the receiving cell in Excel it treating it like text.  I have previously had issues with Excel making wrong assumptions about how to deal with data I export from BIRT.  I am not using spudsoft, but have heard good things about it.  So while I can't answer you question I would suggest broadening your search for solution, this may be an Excel/Microsoft issue not a just a BIRT/Spudsoft issue.  Please post your answer if you find one.

Comment: @JamesJenkins i have updated my question with the BIRT version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long research I have found the reason.

The spudsoft emitter(uk.co.spudsoft.birt.emitters.excel_4.4.1.v201408290142) that comes default with eclipse BIRT(4.4.1) package does not exports the formula ,but the older version(uk.co.spudsoft.birt.emitters.excel_0.8.0.201310230652.jar) downloaded from bitbucket.org/yaytay has export it.(just replaced the whole class files package "uk" from the directory eclipse>plugins>uk.co.spu*** to old version package )

Comment: So you were you able to successfully move to the older spudsoft emitter and export your formulas?

Comment: @JamesJenkins yes, but the old version does not have some features that new versions provides, such as naming excel sheets that taken from a grid name.